# The current path, accounts/home.html, didn't match any of these

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

I've been reading the docs and several questions already answered, but nothing seems to work, so here it the question. I'm starting with django and I can't manage to get rid of the following error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in alpha_trader.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

__debug__/
[name='home']
accounts/update [name='user_change']
accounts/ login/ [name='login']
accounts/ logout/ [name='logout']
accounts/ password_change/ [name='password_change']
accounts/ password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
accounts/ password_reset/ [name='password_reset']
accounts/ password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done']
accounts/ reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']
accounts/ reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete']
accounts/signup [name='user_signup']
The current path, accounts/update.html, didn't match any of these.
```

Hereby my settings.py:

```
# Custom Django auth settings

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'

LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

Hereby urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings

from accounts import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/signup', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='user_signup'),
]
```

hereby accounts/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from accounts import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('accounts/update', views.UserUpdateView.as_view(), name='user_change'),
]
```

hereby accounts/views.py:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('accounts/home.html')
    return render(request, 'accounts/home.html')
```

and finally accounts/models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.html import escape, mark_safe


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    num_of_saved_backtests=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    num_of_online_indicators=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Does anyone sees the error in my code?
IMPORTANT INFO I'm capable to use home when I'm not logged in. It doesn't work one I have managed to log in as a user...

Comment: `return redirect('accounts/home.html')` don't use the file path, but instead you can use the function name, or the url name, depends on the view where you want to redirect to

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just used the url name and it doesn't work... It looks like it enters a loop: [13/Jan/2019 20:58:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/Jan/2019 20:58:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/Jan/2019 20:58:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0

Comment: @Lemayzeur, regarding the function name, there is none, given that this is the home page

Comment: *It looks like it enters a loop* coorect!.

Comment: But in this case the error is given by chrome: Page 127.0.0.1 has redirected you too many times.

Comment: You're right, my approach was about the path. a redirection can't be to the same view in the case the condition will be the same, this will boil down to a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return redirect('accounts/home.html')` In this line, don't redirect to the file path, but instead you can use the *function name*, or the *url name*, depends on the view where you want to redirect to.

```
return redirect('url_name') # or redirect('function_name')
```

Also a redirection can't be to the same view in the case the condition will be the same, this will boil down to a infinite loop.